# Fixed Box jumps on ipad

Tags: css, ipad

I've noticed some odd behaviour on my site using an iPad.
I've narrowed it down to fixed position auto margins. For example:

```css
box{
    display:block;
    border:thin solid black;
    background:yellow;
    position:fixed;
    width:90%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto auto;

    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<box>
    <input/><br/>
    <input/><br/>
</box>

<div style="height:800%; background:blue;">
</div>
```

This works 100% fine in chrome on android and desktop, but on my iPad switching between text boxes causes the box to 'jump' it seems. It's very visually distracting and in some cases causes the box to generate way down the screen.
Is this a known issue with an easy fix?

Answer (score 0):

set `max-width` to the input which might be causing the the jump as the width is not specified in it.

```html
<style>
box{
    display:block;
    border:thin solid black;
    background:yellow;
    position:fixed;
    width:90%;
    height:50%;
    margin:auto auto;

    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
  input{
    max-width: calc(100% - 4px);
  }
</style>


<box>
    <input/><br/>
    <input/><br/>
</box>

<div style="height:800%; background:blue;">
</div>
```

Comment: Nah, it's still doing the jumping thing. It's almost like it doesn't account for the size of the keyboard on the screen. Which is just stupid.

Comment: do u mean it jumps only while getting the keyboard on the screen?

Comment: It jumps anytime you click the input (or switch between the two). It's almost like the ipad is recalculating where the fixed position should be each time.